# What should I do with shortened links in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I read [Shortened Link Cleanup Time!](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6374/shortened-link-cleanup-time) a few days ago, and since then have been on the lookout for shortened links.  However, occasionally I find a shortened link in a comment, and comments, unlike questions and answers, are not editable.

What should I do with these comments?  Should I flag them under "Other" and include an explanation, should I contact the commenter and request that they re-post their comment but with the expanded link, or should I inform a moderator?

Comment: I'd opt for ignoring them. If it's valuable information it shouldn't be in a comment in the first place. It should be in the question or the answer.

Comment: @Oli The irony of your comment is not lost.

Answer (score 5):

To make sure we are on the same page, we are taking about links shortened through external *services* such as goo.gl, non just links shortened through markdown that reveal the original on mouse-over.

Flagging as "Other" with the description explaining it's a shortened link is good; However if it was a up-voted comment that indicates that it was useful at one time, so it may be good to re-post the original link, If the Original user is no longer available .

Also commenting to the user that posted it is a good idea, and is probably the best route with new comments.

Answer (score 5):

Comments are editable by moderators (even after *any* amount of time). I don't know if moderators want to edit a lot of comments to fix obfuscated links, but it is *possible.*

In a situation where the comment provides very important information and has a serious problem (like it says "X is the case" instead "X is *not* the case"), you can custom flag the comment and request moderator editing.

I'd want to hear moderators' viewpoint on this before asking flagging *large* numbers of comments to request editing of obfuscated links. Another thing to consider is that, with the link expanded, the comment might become too long.

Comment: I haven't see a lot in comments, and we cleaned up most all of them, so there won't be en-masse comment flagging - unless we get a surge of new comments using them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is **necessary** to flag a comment just because it have a shortened link.

If you discover that the site where the link point is *fraudulent*, has *malicious code* or *malicious software*, or is containing *SPAM*, then you should flag it explaining the case.